# How to call a command of a rad grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-grid, radgrid, radgridview

i have a rad grid with the following code

```
 <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
   <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:LinkButton ID="Delete" Text="Remove &raquo" 
    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ApartmentId") %>'
     CommandName="RemoveItem" CssClass="Button" runat="server" />
      </ItemTemplate>
   </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

and .CS code as follows

```
protected void radGrid_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Page")
    {
    }
    else
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "RemoveItem")
        {
           Apartments apartAdmin = new Apartment();
           bool deleted = apartAdmin.Delete(int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString()); 
            if (deleted)
            {
                radGrid.Rebind();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I debug it, say I add the breakpoint to this event, it is never fired, is like if it does not see the event for some reason... Can anyone see what the problem may be? This is the mark up of the grid at the top

```
 <telerik:RadGrid ID="radGrid" ShowFooter="true" ShowHeader="true" CaptionAlign="Left"
  runat="server" ForeColor="Black" CellPadding="4" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
  CssClass="Grid" Width="100%" GridLines="None" OnRowCommand="radGrid_RowCommand"
  OnNeedDataSource="radGrid_NeedDataSource" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="true">
  <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="ApartmentID,ApartmentTypeID">
      <CommandItemSettings ShowRefreshButton="true" ShowAddNewRecordButton="false" />
          <Columns>
           <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
       <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:LinkButton ID="Delete" Text="Remove &raquo" 
        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ApartmentId") %>'
         CommandName="RemoveItem" CssClass="Button" runat="server" />
          </ItemTemplate>
       </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
        </Columns>
          <NoRecordsTemplate>
            No related items found</NoRecordsTemplate>
       </MasterTableView>
                    <FooterStyle CssClass="FooterStyle" />
                    <ItemStyle CssClass="RowStyle" />
                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="HeaderStyle" />
                    <AlternatingItemStyle CssClass="AlternatingRowStyle" />
                    <PagerStyle CssClass="PagerStyle" FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last" Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric"
                        AlwaysVisible="true" />
                </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a linkbutton inside an itemtemplate, add a handler for OnClick on the linkbutton itself and the event will surely be fired.

For example:

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs   
 {
         LinkButton button = sender as LinkButton;
          Apartments apartAdmin = new Apartment();
           bool deleted = apartAdmin.Delete(int.Parse(button.CommandArgument.ToString()); 
            if (deleted)
            {
                radGrid.Rebind();
            }

 }
```

Comment: And how would it know which row it is deleting? if there is no RowCommand per se  (using e.CommandName) for example?

Comment: @user710502: Using the CommandArgument. I see you are already passing it in. I will provide an example shortly.

Comment: @user710502: Check my example